# Removing matching sets

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

This is a sample of what my schema and data look like:

```
declare @temp table (rowid int identity(1,1), groupNumber int, typeName varchar(10), valueA int, valueB int, effectiveDate datetime, expiredDate datetime)

insert @temp values (234545, 'Upper', 1, 1000, '1/1/18 11:31:00', '2/1/18 22:01:00')
insert @temp values (234545, 'Lower', 2, 0, '1/1/18 11:31:00', '2/1/18 22:01:00')
insert @temp values (234545, 'Upper', 1, 1000, '2/1/18 22:01:00', '4/15/18 05:39:00')
insert @temp values (234545, 'Lower', 2, 0, '2/1/18 22:01:00', '4/15/18 05:39:00')
insert @temp values (234545, 'Upper', 1, 900, '4/15/18 05:39:00', '6/1/18 10:32:00')
insert @temp values (234545, 'Lower', 2, 0, '4/15/18 05:39:00', '6/1/18 10:32:00')
insert @temp values (234545, 'Upper', 1, 900, '4/15/18 06:39:00', '6/1/18 10:32:00')
insert @temp values (234545, 'Lower', 2, 0, '4/15/18 06:39:00', '6/1/18 10:32:00')
insert @temp values (234545, 'Upper', 1, 800, '6/1/18 10:32:00', null)
insert @temp values (234545, 'Lower', 2, 0, '6/1/18 10:32:00', null)

select *
from @temp
```

For each group number there are multiple sets, a set being defined by the effective date, and the effective date always being equal to the expired date of the previous set.  So in the example there are 5 sets, and what I want to do is remove the superfluous sets, which would be rows 3/4 and 5/6.  I only care about a new set when valueA or valueB has changed.  Ultimately my goal is to clean up this data in a production database by looping through the groups one at a time since about 60% of the rows reflect no change at all from one set to the next in terms of anything important (i.e. typeName, valueA, valueB).

The catch is that when I delete those 4 rows I also need to set the expiredDate of the first two rows to be equal to the effectiveDate of rows 7 and 8, since those always need to line up.

The other catch is that I'd like to run a script (maybe via SQL Agent job) that loops through the table (obvs not a table variable in production) and deletes the rows and updates the expiredDates using a new transaction for each groupNumber.  If I stop the job before it's done and it's in the middle of a transaction (which is likely), is there a way to automatically have it roll back?

Comment: Why don't you want to delete the first two rows (in the order of the `INSERT` statements), they're expired too? And why do you want to delete them in the first place. You could keep them as history and only retrieve valid rows by comparing the time stamps against now.

Comment: Please show us the expected result and explain the required logic in a bit more detail.

Comment: I have code for this that mostly works, but problem is that the pairs as you describe it appear to be only linked by the fact they are next to each other by virtue of the identity key. Is that the only way we know that the last row for example is not a later version of the 2nd row? Both have everything except dates matching. If the group number were different then I can make it work!

Comment: They are linked by the dates, i.e. the effective date of one set is equal to the expired date of the previous set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the answer:

```
declare @temp table (rowid int identity(1,1), groupNumber int, typeName varchar(10), valueA int, valueB int, effectiveDate datetime, expiredDate datetime)

insert @temp values (234545, 'Upper', 1, 1000, '1/1/18 11:31:00', '2/1/18 22:01:00')
insert @temp values (234545, 'Lower', 2, 0, '1/1/18 11:31:00', '2/1/18 22:01:00')
insert @temp values (234545, 'Upper', 1, 1000, '2/1/18 22:01:00', '4/15/18 05:39:00')
insert @temp values (234545, 'Lower', 2, 0, '2/1/18 22:01:00', '4/15/18 05:39:00')
insert @temp values (234545, 'Upper', 1, 900, '4/15/18 05:39:00', '6/1/18 10:32:00')
insert @temp values (234545, 'Lower', 2, 0, '4/15/18 05:39:00', '6/1/18 10:32:00')
insert @temp values (234545, 'Upper', 1, 900, '4/15/18 06:39:00', '6/1/18 10:32:00')
insert @temp values (234545, 'Lower', 2, 0, '4/15/18 06:39:00', '6/1/18 10:32:00')
insert @temp values (234545, 'Upper', 1, 800, '6/1/18 10:32:00', null)
insert @temp values (234545, 'Lower', 2, 0, '6/1/18 10:32:00', null)

select * from @temp

DECLARE MY_CURSOR Cursor STATIC 
FOR SELECT DISTINCT groupNumber FROM @temp 

Open My_Cursor 
DECLARE @groupNumber int
Fetch NEXT FROM MY_Cursor INTO @groupNumber
While (@@FETCH_STATUS <> -1)
BEGIN
            IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temp') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #temp  

            SELECT RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY rp2.groupNumber ORDER BY rp2.EffectiveDate) AS TheRank, rp2.groupNumber, rp2.EffectiveDate,
                    TotalvalueA = SUM(rp2.valueA), ChecksumTotal = SUM(ISNULL(rp2.valueA,0) + ISNULL(rp2.valueB,0)), --assumes valueA and valueB can never be reversed
                                    (
                                        Select CAST(rp.typeName as varchar(2)) + ',' AS [text()]
                                        From @temp rp
                                        Where rp.groupNumber = rp2.groupNumber AND rp.groupNumber = @groupNumber
                                            and rp.EffectiveDate = rp2.EffectiveDate
                                        GROUP BY rp.typeName
                                        ORDER BY MIN(rp.typeName)                    
                                        For XML PATH ('')
                                    ) typesXML,
                    DeleteSet = 0
            INTO #temp
            FROM @temp rp2
            WHERE rp2.groupNumber = @groupNumber
            GROUP BY rp2.groupNumber, rp2.EffectiveDate

            UPDATE t2
            SET DeleteSet = 1
            From #temp t1
            LEFT JOIN #temp t2 ON t1.TheRank = t2.TheRank - 1
            WHERE t1.TotalvalueA = t2.TotalvalueA AND t1.ChecksumTotal = t2.ChecksumTotal AND t1.typesXML = t2.typesXML
            AND t2.TheRank <> (SELECT MAX(TheRank) FROM #temp)

            BEGIN TRAN

            DELETE rp
            FROM @temp rp 
            JOIN #temp t ON t.groupNumber = rp.groupNumber AND rp.EffectiveDate = t.EffectiveDate AND t.DeleteSet = 1

            if @@error != 0 raiserror('Script failed', 20, -1) with log

            UPDATE rp
            SET ExpiredDate = t2.NewExpiredDate
            FROM @temp rp
            JOIN (SELECT * , NewExpiredDate = LEAD(EffectiveDate) OVER (ORDER BY TheRank) FROM #temp WHERE DeleteSet = 0) t2 ON t2.groupNumber = rp.groupNumber AND rp.EffectiveDate = t2.EffectiveDate
            JOIN #temp t ON t.TheRank = t2.TheRank + 1
            WHERE rp.groupNumber = @groupNumber AND t2.NewExpiredDate IS NOT NULL AND rp.ExpiredDate <> t2.NewExpiredDate
            AND t.DeleteSet = 1

            if @@error != 0 raiserror('Script failed', 20, -1) with log

            PRINT 'No Errors ... Committing changes for ' + CAST(@groupNumber as varchar(15))
            COMMIT
            --select * from @temp
            --ROLLBACK
            --dbcc opentran
    WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:00:005';
    FETCH NEXT FROM MY_CURSOR INTO @groupNumber
END
CLOSE MY_CURSOR
DEALLOCATE MY_CURSOR
GO
```

Answer (score 1):

You can identify rows with higher and lower values with windows functions generating two ranks, one ascending and the other descending.

Then you can filter only the values that ranked first:

```
;WITH summary AS (
    SELECT  p.rowid 
           ,p.groupNumber 
           ,p.typeName 
           ,p.valueA 
           ,p.valueB 
           ,p.effectiveDate 
           ,p.expiredDate 
           ,rank() OVER(PARTITION BY p.groupNumber ORDER BY p.effectiveDate ) AS rk_min
           ,rank() OVER(PARTITION BY p.groupNumber ORDER BY p.effectiveDate desc) AS rk_max
      FROM @temp p)
SELECT s.rowid, s. groupNumber, s.typeName, s.valueA, s.valueB,
       s.effectiveDate, s.expiredDate 
FROM summary s
WHERE s.rk_min = 1 or s.rk_max=1
ORDER BY s.rowid
```

Results:

[image]

If you want to identify the inner values between the extremes just change the where condition to `WHERE s.rk_min > 1 and s.rk_max > 1`:

```
;WITH summary AS (
    SELECT  p.rowid 
           ,p.groupNumber 
           ,p.typeName 
           ,p.valueA 
           ,p.valueB 
           ,p.effectiveDate 
           ,p.expiredDate 
           ,rank() OVER(PARTITION BY p.groupNumber ORDER BY p.effectiveDate ) AS rk_min
           ,rank() OVER(PARTITION BY p.groupNumber ORDER BY p.effectiveDate desc) AS rk_max
      FROM @temp p)
SELECT s.rowid, s. groupNumber, s.typeName, s.valueA, s.valueB, 
       s.effectiveDate, s.expiredDate 
FROM summary s
WHERE s.rk_min > 1 and s.rk_max > 1
ORDER BY s.rowid
```

Results:

[image]

Comment: This works! It doesn't answer the question about stopping gracefully or handling the expiredDate updates but it answers the important part.

Comment: Upon inspection this is not correct as it removes all sets between the first and the last whether or not there were changes. I'm updating my question to clarify that I need to keep all changes to valueA and valueB.

Answer (score 1):

This is not **final Script** since there is some doubts.

@Doubts 1 : what is superfluous rows/sets ?why 3/4 and 5/6 rows are superfluous ?.Answer should cover all possible scenario.

@Doubt 2 : First 2 rows expiredDate will be updated with expiredDate of which row of last 2 rows. What is the relation between First 2 rows and last 2 rows while updating ?

```
CREATE table #temp (rowid int identity(1,1), groupNumber int, typeName varchar(10), valueA int, valueB int
, effectiveDate datetime, expiredDate datetime,isLineup int default(0))

insert #temp values (234545, 'Upper', 1, 1000, '1/1/18 11:31:00', '2/1/18 22:01:00',0)
insert #temp values (234545, 'Lower', 2, 0, '1/1/18 11:31:00', '2/1/18 22:01:00',0)
insert #temp values (234545, 'Upper', 1, 1000, '2/1/18 22:01:00', '4/15/18 05:39:00',0)
insert #temp values (234545, 'Lower', 2, 0, '2/1/18 22:01:00', '4/15/18 05:39:00',0)
insert #temp values (234545, 'Upper', 1, 900, '4/15/18 05:39:00', '6/1/18 10:32:00',0)
insert #temp values (234545, 'Lower', 2, 0, '4/15/18 05:39:00', '6/1/18 10:32:00',0)
insert #temp values (234545, 'Upper', 1, 900, '6/1/18 10:32:00', null,0)
insert #temp values (234545, 'Lower', 2, 0, '6/1/18 10:32:00', null,0)



CREATE table #temp1 (rowid int,effectiveDate datetime,Flag int )
--select * from #temp

-- Main Script

Begin Try
BEGIN TRANSACTION

-- Criteria to decide superflous rows
insert into #temp1 (rowid ,effectiveDate ,Flag  )
select top 2 rowid,effectiveDate,0 Flag from #temp where isLineup=0 ORDER by rowid
insert into #temp1 (rowid ,effectiveDate ,Flag  )
select top 2 rowid,effectiveDate,1 Flag from #temp where isLineup=0 ORDER by rowid desc
--- End

delete FROM #temp 
where not EXISTS(select 1 from #temp1 c where c.rowid=#temp.rowid )

update C 
set expiredDate=ca.effectiveDate
,isLineup=1
from #temp c
cross apply(select top 1 effectiveDate from #temp1 c1 where c1.Flag=1 )ca
where c.isLineup=0

COMMIT

End Try
begin Catch

if (@@trancount>0)
ROLLBACK TRAN

-- log error

end Catch

-- End Main

select * from #temp
select * from #temp1

drop TABLE #temp
drop table #temp1
```

Comment: I updated my question to make it more obvious what should be removed.

Comment: @influent, sorry in fact it is not clear to anybody. Why don't you put them in words. More the clear better the solution.